# Converting date format in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have similar different file of the format `backup_2016-26-10_16-30-00` is it possible to rename using bash script to `backup_26-10-2016_16:30:00` for all files.
Kindly suggest some method to fix this.

**Original file:**

`backup_2016-30-10_12-00-00`

**Expected output:**

`backup_30-10-2016_12:00:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform only the name transformation, you can use `awk`:

```
echo 'backup_2016-30-10_12-00-00' |
  awk -F'[_-]' '{ print $1 "_" $3 "-" $4 "-" $2 "_" $5 ":" $6 ":" $7 }'
```

As [fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui) points out in a comment, `awk`'s `printf` function may be tidier in this case:

```
echo 'backup_2016-30-10_12-00-00' |
  awk -F'[_-]' '{ printf "%s_%s-%s-%s_%s:%s:%s\n", $1,$3,$4,$2,$5,$6,$7 }'
```

---

That said, your specific Linux distro may come with a `rename` tool that allows you to do the same while performing actual file renaming.

Comment: That was so perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

with `perl` based `rename` command:

```
$ touch backup_2016-30-10_12-00-00 backup_2016-26-10_16-30-00

$ rename -n 's/(\d{4})-([^_]+)_(\d+)-(\d+)-/$2-$1_$3:$4:/' backup*
rename(backup_2016-26-10_16-30-00, backup_26-10-2016_16:30:00)
rename(backup_2016-30-10_12-00-00, backup_30-10-2016_12:00:00)
```

remove the `-n` option for actual renaming

Answer (score 2):

`rename` is for this task

```
$ rename 's/_(\d{4})-(\d\d-\d\d)_(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)$/_$2-$1_$3:$4:$5/' backup_2016-30-10_12-00-00
```

but not sure will be simpler

Answer (score 1):

you can also this script;

```
#!/bin/bash
fileName=$1
prefix=$(echo ${fileName} | cut -d _ -f1)
date=$(echo ${fileName} | cut -d _ -f2)
time=$(echo ${fileName} | cut -d _ -f3)

year=$(echo ${date} | cut -d - -f1)
day=$(echo ${date} | cut -d '-' -f2)
month=$(echo ${date} | cut -d '-' -f3)

formatedTime=$(echo $time |  sed 's/-/:/g')

formatedDate=$day"-"$month"-"$year

formatedFileName=$prefix"_"$formatedDate"_"$formatedTime

echo $formatedFileName
```

Eg;

```
user@host:/tmp$ ./test.sh backup_2016-30-10_12-00-00
backup_30-10-2016_12:00:00
```